# Order posts by ACF checkbox

Tags: query-posts, order

I would like to order the posts (archive.php) by listing the ones with the ACF checkbox "Premium" first, could someone please offer some advice?:) This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?>
<?php $posts = query_posts( $query_string . 'meta_key=premium&orderby=meta_value&order=asc' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!--the content -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php bones_page_navi(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <!--Error Message-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks so much :)

Comment: I believe that posts without this checkbox checked will not have the `premium` post meta at all, so your query as written will likely only show "premium" posts. If so, you may have to use two loops - one for the "premium" posts and another for regular posts. During the first loop, store "premium" post IDs to an array that you can pass as the `post__not_in` parameter in the second loop.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help. I'm still battling a bit though. At the moment I'm using query_posts, should I rather be using WP_Query? I'm not quite sure how to implement the two loops. This is what I have so far:

`<?php $posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&meta_key=premium-posts&orderby=meta_value&compare=LIKE&order=asc' ); ?>`